# Bash script retrieve list of full URLs from file of short URLs

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have a file that contains short links on each line that look something like: "http://short.ly/1Typn4C"

I'm able to follow all redirects and write the final full url to a file using this curl command:

```
curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} http://short.ly/1Typn4C | xargs echo >> ./full_urls.txt
```

When looping through each line of the file with the same command it just ends up writing the original short URL to the file:

```
while read line
do
  finalLink="$(curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "$line")"
  echo "$finalLink" >> ./full_urls.txt
done < ./short_urls.txt
```

Clearly I am misunderstanding something about how shell scripts work.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me, as it should.

```
$ echo 'https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ' >./short_urls.txt

$ while read line
> do
>   finalLink="$(curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "$line")"
>   echo "$finalLink" >> ./full_urls.txt
> done < ./short_urls.txt

$ cat ./full_urls.txt
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtu.be
```